# Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 255

Tags: visual-c++

I am migrating one project from VC2006 to VS2015.
In the project one of the module is giving below error while compilation.

```
Performing Custom Build Tools
preESQL LkDataStore.ecp LkDataStore_or.pc o
preESQL done!
C:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\proc LkDataStore_or.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Wed May 17 22:40:05 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: C:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\precomp\admin\pcscfg.cfg
Performing Custom Build Tools
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 255.
```

The project has 10 files and till 7th file no issues, after that I see the above error. I had removed the last 3 files from the project and compiled, build was success.

The module has .ecp files as it should support both ORACLE and INFORMIX databases

I am not able find out the root cause for the issue.

can anyone help me in the above issue.

Comment: You probably can't find it because you are focusing on the wrong tool that failed.  It does not have anything to do with databases.  It is the next project whose custom build event fails.  Without you posting the content of that build event you can't get a guess.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment, we have some path setting based on what database, i feel is the path settings cause 'input line is too long'?